# Como proteger los ViewBag que viajan por el buscador

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

Estoy mandando datos de una lista a una vista, el problema es que esos datos se muestran en el buscador y cualquiera puede cambiar su valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Listado**

```
    @model IEnumerable<wsCharlas.Models.ClsCharla>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MostraCharlas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>MostraCharlas</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <strong>Seleccione una sede: </strong>
    @Html.DropDownList("sed", (SelectList)ViewBag.allSedes, "Seleccione una Sede", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Crear Charla", "CrearCharla", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID_Charla)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.titulo_Charla)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.descrip_Charla)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha_Charla)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.hora_Charla)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lugar_Charla)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sede_Charla)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.requisito_Charla)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.titulo_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descrip_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fecha_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hora_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lugar_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sede_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.requisito_Charla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Ver Inscritos", "MostrarInscritos", new { id = item.ID_Charla }) | <!--ESTO SOLO DEBE APARECER EN EL ADMINISTRADOR-->
                @Html.ActionLink("Inscribirse", "CrearInteresado", new {
                                                                           id = item.ID_Charla,
                                                                           titulo = item.titulo_Charla,
                                                                           descripcion = item.descrip_Charla,
                                                                           fecha = item.fecha_Charla,
                                                                           hora = item.hora_Charla,
                                                                           direccion = item.lugar_Charla }) | <!--ESTO SOLO DEBE APARECER EN LOS INTERESADOS-->

                @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "EditarCharlas", new { id = item.ID_Charla }) | <!--ESTO SOLO DEBE APARECER EN EL ADMINISTRADOR-->
                @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "EliminarCharla", new { id = item.ID_Charla }) | <!--ESTO SOLO DEBE APARECER EN EL ADMINISTRADOR-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: ¿Primero hay un listado, y en cada registro hay un enlace?, ¿podrías pegar el enlace que tiene cada registro?, ¿o la ruta larga aparece cuando das click en el boton create?

Comment: Ya lo actualice amigo @Kamousagi

Comment: @Html.ActionLink no oculta parametros. Tendrias que usar algun envio POST para ocultar los parametros, por ejemplo enviando soo el ID, y al otro lado recuperar los datos desde tu BD o el almacen de datos que uses.

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu url despues de cargar la pagina, eliminando los parametros , revisa la actualizacion de url mediante javascript, pushstate

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: así es amigo @fredyfx

Comment: Todo lo hice con JSON

Comment: ya excelente, ahora publica la respuesta y en 24 horas la marcas como aceptada, así serás el héroe de más usuarios con el mismo escenario y a su vez, estarás colaborando con la buena salud del sitio (por el porcentaje de preguntas resueltas). En la parte de abajo hay una caja de texto que dice "Tu Respuesta".

Comment: ahora lo estoy colocando :)

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Muchas gracias bro :D